# want to make a program that selects out prime numbers. don't get why my program doesn't work

Tags: java

whenever I try to run this program, it first shows "The prime's upper bound?" After inserting an integer and pressing enter, I don't see anything then. I want it to display some "false" values, but I can't find where the problem is. And the Java doesn't show where the problem is.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Lab11 {

    static int n;
    boolean [] primedetermine = new boolean [n];
    int [] list;

    public static void main (String[]args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.print ("The prime's upper bound? ");
        int max = in.nextInt();
        boolean prime [] = new boolean [max];
        computePrimes (prime);
    }

    public static void computePrimes(boolean[] primedetermine) {
        for (int x = 0; x<n; x++) {
            primedetermine [x] = false;
        }
        for (int prm = 2; prm <= n; prm++) {
            for (int prm2 = 2; prm * prm2 <= 21; prm++) {
                primedetermine [prm * prm2 -1] = true;
            }
        }
        for (int x = 1; x<=n; x++){
            if (primedetermine[x-1] == false);
                System.out.println(primedetermine[x-1]);
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: Have you debugged your code? n will always be 0, so your loops won't iterate

Comment: Take a look [here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-determine-a-prime-number-in-java/)

Comment: Your n value is never initialized, such mistake is inappropriate for someone who calls himself geniushacker ))

Comment: This is not a code debugging service

Answer (score 1):

You are using the variable `n` which is never initialized (so it's 0 by default, and your loops are never entered) :

```
for (int x = 0; x<n; x++)
```

instead of `n` use `primedetermine.length`.

That's just one problem. `primedetermine [prm * prm2 -1]` will throw an exception, since `prm * prm2 -1` will exceed the range of the array.